# Oozie shell action failing

Tags: hive, bigdata, cloudera, oozie

I am trying to test oozie shell action in my cloudera vm (quickstart vm). When running a simple hdfs command (hadoop fs -put ...) script its working but when I am triggering a hive script the oozie job is finished with status **"KILLED"**. On oozie consol only error message I am getting is

> "Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]"

While the underlying job in history server(name node logs) is coming as SUCCEEDED. Below are oozie job details :

```
workflow.xml
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5" name="WorkFlow1">
      <start to="shell-node" />
          <action name="shell-node">
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <exec>${myscript}</exec>
            <file>${myscriptpath}#${myscript}</file>
            <capture-output/>
        </shell>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
        <kill name="fail">
          <message>Workflow failed, error
            message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}] </message>
        </kill>
        <end name="end" />
</workflow-app>
------------------------------------
job.properties
nameNode=hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020
jobTracker=hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8032
queueName=default
myscript=test.sh
myscriptpath=${nameNode}/oozie/sl/test.sh
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/oozie/sl/
workflowAppUri=${nameNode}/oozie/sl/
-----------------------------------------------
test.sh
hive -e "create table test2 as select * from test"
```

Would really appreciate if anyone can point me in direction I am getting it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good if you have a look into the Oozie Hive action.

Its pretty easy to configure. Hive action will take care of setting everything.

https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/DG_HiveActionExtension.html

To connect hive , you need to explicitly add the hive-site.xml or the Hive server details for it to connect.